# Moving Image when scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css

I learnt from this fiddle( http://jsfiddle.net/MMZ2h/4/ ) how to move the image when scrolled, but if you keep scrolling up and down for a while, the image eventually moves out of bounds. Why is that? and how do we fix that?

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$("div").scroll(function (event) {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();
if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    $('img').animate({top: '-=10'}, 5);
} else {
    $('img').animate({top: '+=10'}, 5);
}
lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as expected because each time your scroll event is triggered, your image position animation is performed. But this animation takes 10 milliseconds to end and because you specify an increment or decrement based on the current position, so your position will be computed based on a wrong position and will break after some time.

Try this code

```js
var delta = 2; // specify the delta you want
var initialImgScrollTop = $("img").offset().top; // get the current top position of your image
var initialImgScrollLeft = $("img").offset().left;
$("#div1").scroll(function (event) {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
 $("img").animate({ top: initialImgScrollTop - st * delta }, 10); // compute the position your image should be
});

var scrollHeight = $('#div2').prop('scrollHeight') - $('#div2').innerHeight(); // get the scroll height
var initialMiddleScroll = scrollHeight / 2; // compute the middle scroll
$("#div2").scrollTop(initialMiddleScroll); // set the scroll to middle so you can go left and right
$("#div2").scroll(function (event) {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
 $("img").animate({ left: initialImgScrollLeft + (st - initialMiddleScroll) * delta }, 10); // compute the position your image should be
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 150px;
    height:150px;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: inline-block;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    top:400px;
    left:150px;
    width:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">This is just some stupid text unworthy of being read, so please don't waste
    <br>your time reading this nonesense.
    <br>Hey! why are you still reading this garbage?
    <br>Stop reading now and start doing something useful, such as getting this leaf to move up
    <br>while you scroll this page.
    <br>On second thought, maybe just continue reading.
    <br>This might be more productive then whatever
    <br>it is you were doing before.</div>
<div id="div2">This is just some stupid text unworthy of being read, so please don't waste
    <br>your time reading this nonesense.
    <br>Hey! why are you still reading this garbage?
    <br>Stop reading now and start doing something useful, such as getting this leaf to move up
    <br>while you scroll this page.
    <br>On second thought, maybe just continue reading.
    <br>This might be more productive then whatever
    <br>it is you were doing before.</div>
<img src="http://sweetclipart.com/multisite/sweetclipart/files/imagecache/middle/nature_seasons_spring_leaf_green.png">
```

-----UPDATE-----

I will try to explain precisely what breaks in your code.
Let's begin with the ideal case when your code works:

- you scroll down
- the final scroll position is computed to 10px (you increment from 10 to 10)
- the scroll triggers the animation
- the animation begins
- the scroll position goes from 0px to 10px
- the animation ends
- you scroll down again, loop...

Ok this works but in most of cases, you will scroll multiple times during the animation:

- you scroll down
- the final scroll position 1 is computed to 10px
- the scroll triggers the animation 1
- the animation 1 begins
- the scroll position goes from 0px to 3px
- you scroll down again
- the final scroll position 2 is computed to 13px (3 + 10)
- the animation 2 begins
- the scroll position goes 3px to 10px (the final position of your animation 1)
- the animation 1 ends
- the scroll position goes from 10px to 13px (the final position of your animation 2)
- the animation 2 ends

You see that after two scroll events, you have 13px as scroll position while you expect it to be 20px.

My approach is not to depend on the relative value of positioning (based on the previous position of the image what is its new position) but instead to depend on the absolute value (based on the scroll of the div what is the new position of the image).

Hope you understand! If anything unclear, let me know.

PS: I update the code snippet so you can see how you can do for the left-right animation.

Comment: Thanks Wing-on, your answer works perfectly! This is just what I wanted, but I would like to understand the problem more. Can you please elaborate on the animation takes 10 ms to end part?

Comment: Adding an update, how would I make this work for left and right instead of top? If I simply replace top with left, the image snaps to a location and then animates from there.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Wing-On. I perfectly understood what's the problem. For scrolling left and right however you suggest to compute the middle scroll height and then use that to move the image left and right. Is there any other way to do this? Because I'm animating the image when the window is scrolled and the animation is at the top of the page. Thanks again for your help so far

Comment: You're welcome. I choose the middle scroll so you can move the image to the left or to the right in your example. Please describe more precisely the behaviour you want to achieve when you scroll in the page. Is the image a background image? Is your image going in one direction and after some scroll in another one?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made this earlier. This is what I'm trying to achieve:  
  http://jsfiddle.net/2t8k87cg/                                                              However the code breaks after some time and the images go out of the window. This is why I wanted to know how to move the images left and right as well and why the middle scroll code would be hard to use. Sorry if i'm asking too much of you but this problem has been annoying me for quite a while.

Comment: YES! You are awesome. Period. Please send me a message if you need any help at all in logo or banner design. I will be sure to return the favour!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mouse Wheel event`, and extract `delta` from event.

See my example, i hope it help:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].addEventListener('wheel', 
 function(e) {
  if(e.wheelDelta > 0) {
    $('img').animate({top: '+=3'}, 10);
  } else {
    $('img').animate({top: '-=3'}, 10);
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qnqvzh87/

Try to find your delta values.

Comment: I want it to move when you scroll using the arrow keys and by clicking the scrollbar as well, not just the scroll wheel.

Answer (score 0):

It's tested code, you can try the following.

```js
jQuery(window).on('load resize scroll', function() {
  jQuery('.bg-static').each(function() {
    var windowTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var elementTop = jQuery(this).offset().top;
    var leftPosition = windowTop - elementTop;
      jQuery(this)
        .find('.bg-move')
        .css({ left: leftPosition });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.section {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 920px;
  min-height: 75vh;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #48c9b0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.section.bg-static {
  background-color: #85c1e9;
  background-image: url(https://webmadewell.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/img-blog-background-move-scrolling-bg.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.section .bg-move {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://webmadewell.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/img-blog-background-move-scrolling-boat.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  Scroll down to see the effect
</div>
<div class="section bg-static">
  <div class="bg-move"></div>
</div>
<div class="section">
  The boat image is moving only when scrolling. 
</div>
```